# jquery hoverclass removed after animation

Tags: jquery

I have a div that i make draggable using the following code:

```
$("#start").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'startHover',
    drop: handleStartDropEvent,
    tolerance: "pointer",
    accept: ".cell",
    containment: ".cascade",
});
```

then somewhere in my code i animate this same div using this code:

```
var formHtml = $("#form")[0].outerHTML;
if ((formHtml.indexOf("row") <= 0)) {
    alert("Warning: An empty form cannot be submitted");
    $("#start").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#start").css("color", "white");
    $("#start").animate({
        backgroundColor: "initial",
        color: "black"
    }, 700);
    return false;
}
```

I  have noticed that after I animate the hoverclass of this div doesn't work anymore. It's still draggable but it doesn't change the class on hover like it does before the animation.

I tried setting the hoverclass again after the animation but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How can you tell the class is not added?  If it is based on color and/or background-color, you have made calls to `css` which will override the class in the case of those properties.

Comment: you are correct! let me reply my post with the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Montagne is right, the solution was to remove those attributes after the animation is complete, like so:

```
var formHtml = $("#form")[0].outerHTML;
if ((formHtml.indexOf("row") <= 0)) {
    alert("Warning: An empty form cannot be submitted");
    $("#start").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#start").css("color", "white");
    $("#start").animate({
        backgroundColor: "initial",
        color: "black"
    }, 700, function () { $("#start").attr('style', ''); });
    return false;
}
```

Cheers James!

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly less heavy-handed approach (than removing the entire style attribute as in your solution), you could also just clear the relevant css properties like so:

```
$("#start").css("background-color", "red");
$("#start").css("color", "white");
$("#start").animate({
    backgroundColor: "initial",
    color: "black"
}, 700, function () { 
    $("#start").css('color', '')
               .css('background-color', ''); 
});
```

This will clear the `color` and `background-color` css properties so that the css defined for our hover class can take effect.